# how to get my robot to perform work

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

I am a learning js. I'm trying to get my robot to do work. Here is what I have come up with: What am I doing wrong?

```
var robot ={
  powerOn: false,
  command: "Sweeping the floor",
  duration: 10

  function doWork(command, duration) {
    if (powerOn!= ) {                   
    alert(this.doWork)= "My current task is: " + command + ". Duration: " + duration + " minutes." + BR;  
  }
}   
robot.doWork();
```

Comment: Just curious, which robot? ^^

Comment: Please add more information. Also format the code properly

Comment: I created a object named robot in the source code above

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code.  You forgot to finish the conditional statement in your `if`.  Aside from that, we really have no idea what you're asking.  Are you getting an error?  Is the code not doing what you expect?  Please be specific, we don't actually know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Nayan. I'm very..very new to this. I thought it was formatted correctly. Also what other information do you need?

Comment: Your power on condition is missing an argument, and you're trying to assign a string to a method call. You are also using parameters in the `doWork` function that are not passed in.

Comment: Okay, I hear its not formatted correctly and Im missing information.

Comment: I dont know what other information I can give you. Sorry to bother everyone and thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try to read javascript tutorial ?

Comment: The code you have written in not valid.

Comment: You can have a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/ZuSvMrAhOr0agNrDlz4x Please explain what you want your code to do

Answer (score 2):

I think you're conflating object literal syntax with new `class` syntax. See the notes below for the object literal version.

```
var robot = {
  powerOn: false,
  command: "Sweeping the floor",
  duration: 10, // <-- include comma

  // Assign the function like you did with the other object properties
  doWork: function(command, duration) {

    // ---v---reference the robot via `this` (or `robot`) and delete the `!=`
    if (this.powerOn) {   

       // move the `)` to the end and delete the `this.doWork`, `=`, and `+ BR`
      alert("My current task is: " + command + ". Duration: " + duration + " minutes."); 

    } // <--include the closing brace
  }
}   
robot.doWork("vacuum", 10); // pass some data

robot.powerOn = true; // power it on

robot.doWork("vacuum", 10); // try again now that the power is on
```

Comment: Hey, you did a great job explaining the edits to her code! I upvoted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, if the function `doWork` is to be a property of the `robot` object, you need to format it so `doWork` is a property that contains a function, like so:

```
doWork: function () {
    if (this.powerOn !== false) {
        alert("My current task is: " + this.command + ". Duration: " + this.duration + " minutes.");
    }
}
```

I was confused, also, because you are accepting arguments for a `command` and `duration`, but you have them as properties of the object which never get altered. I interpreted your code to prefer using `robot`'s object's properties instead of arguments. Thus, I removed the arguments. You could update it to accept arguments, change the object's properties, and then fire the `alert` to get the same result, but get the opportunity to change the task, like so:

```
doWork: function (command, duration) {
    if (this.powerOn !== false) {

        if (this.command === '') {
            this.command = command;
        }

        if (this.duration === '') {
            this.duration = duration
        }

        alert("My current task is: " + this.command + ". Duration: " + this.duration + " minutes.");
    }
}
```

You're also not finishing your evaluation of the `powerOn` property. Presumably, you want `powerOn` to evaluate to `true` before the robot can attempt to do any work. I added a start function, but you could also directly change the object's property.

I put this into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekeyte/gfxo9sdk/) for you so you can play around with it a bit. You also should look at the [MDN JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) for `alert`, so you can understand how to use that better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try do this :

```
var robot = {
    powerOn: false,
    command: "Sweeping the floor",
    duration: 10
};


function doWork(cmd) {
    if (cmd.powerOn) {
        alert("My current task is: " + cmd.command + ". Duration: " + cmd.duration + " minutes.");
    }
}
doWork(robot);
```

*Switch powerOn to true, to get alert.*

Comment: thank you. I will try that.

Comment: how would I use this.doWork to make the robot do housework?

Comment: Replace "false" by "true".